# ¿Qué son "hornos de tabique" y "mirruña de caudal" en el español de Colombia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, palabras-raras, colombia

Me quedé asombrado al leer el libro [Buscando dentro del Caos](http://books.google.ru/books?id=SrhI41rkmw8C&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=Buscando%20dentro%20del%20Caos&source=bl&ots=3BRh5nvuat&sig=dD1YE5Fj9Z0uzO4Hd_0_Ps0VG9I&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=0oYHUsjJEoOI4ATN9YDoAQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Buscando%20dentro%20del%20Caos&f=false) escrito por [César Pellicer](http://grammata.co/author/27785/cesar-pellicer), particularmente desde sus frases abundantes en palabras totalmente misteriosas para mí. Por ejemplo:

> Caminar era mi premio de cada ocho días, mi padre me explicaba qué era
>   cada cosa… el acueducto marcado con la presencia de esas columnas de
>   concreto descomunales, gigantescas para mí, los **hornos de tabique**,
>   los alfalfares de las haciendas cercanas, el cauce del río Churubusco
>   que nunca entendí por qué le decían río a esa **mirruña de caudal**, las
>   arboledas que yo admiraba por su soledad y su mansedumbre, para
>   rematar cada domingo de cada mes, de muchos años, en el viejo museo de
>   Churubusco…

Quizás mi español se ha deteriorado mucho después de años sin hablarlo, pero ¿qué son los *hornos de tabique*? ¿Se trata de sensaciones del calor en el pecho? O ¿habla el autor literalmente sobre algunas construcciones técnicas?

Y ¿qué es *la mirruña de caudal*? ¿Es un sonido?

Answer (score 10):

**hornos de tabique**: No soy de Colombia pero si se refiere a lo mismo que en México es literalmente un horno hecho de tabiques o ladrillos.

Además de utilizarse en la panaderia tradicional latina son muy comunes en Italia y es donde tradicionalmente se cocinaban las pizzas. En la parte inferior/posterior del horno se coloca leña y en el frente el alimento a cocer, la piedra preserva de manera natural el calor por lo que son muy efectivos.
 [image]

**Mirruña**: lo utilizamos para decir que algo es muy pequeño. La *mirruña de caudal* es porque el rio es en realidad ya muy escaso. Utilizando otro ejemplo si te pagan muy poco por tu trabajo puedes decir que *te pagan una mirruña.* etc.

Answer (score 3):

Según el diccionario (RAE y Oxford) "tabique" significa "ladrillo". En el contexto del párrafo, el padre le muestra al narrador las cosas. Entonces, "los hornos de tabique" son "brick ovens". Pero el diccionario dice que es una palabra mexicana.

Según el diccionario Oxford "mirruña" significa "tiny bit".

Answer (score 3):

Si te sirve de consuelo, yo soy argentino, y también me cuesta entender esas expresiones, en parte debo adivinarlas. (De paso, la prosa de ese párrafo no me causa buena impresión).

"Horno" es "oven". En Argentina, "tabique" es una pared delgada, o división de ambientes (like cubicle partitions).  Aquí parece que quiere decir otra cosa.

"Mirruña de caudal": "caudal" es la cantidad de agua que transporta un río (no estoy seguro de que en inglés exista esta palabra). A river that transport a great volume ("caudal") of water is "un río caudaloso" o "un río de gran caudal". Adivino (y el diccionario confirma) que "mirruña" es una manera local -probablemente coloquial- de decir "a little bit", a ridiculously poor amount.